# How to get the status icon of an entire project in Team City 10

Tags: teamcity

As the title says, I'm trying to get the status icon of an entire project (not just a build or a build configuration) in TC10.

For example, say I have the following project with build config structure:

```
PROJECT
 - BUILD CONFIG 1
    + BRANCH A (default) OK 
    + BRANCH B           OK
    + BRANCH C           OK
 - BUILD CONFIG 2
    + BRANCH A           OK 
    + BRANCH B           FAILED
    + BRANCH C           OK
```

I want that the icon shows a FAILED status, because one of the builds failed in my project.

I read the documentation at https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/REST+API#RESTAPI-BuildStatusIcon and, based on the examples, I came up with this URL:

```
https://server/app/rest/builds/aggregated/strob:
    (
     branch:(
             buildType:project(PROJECT_ID),
             policy:active_history_and_active_vcs_branches
            ),
     locator:(
             buildType:project:(PROJECT_ID)
             )
    )/statusIcon.svg
```

I "tested" this on 2 projects with the same structure and status as above, one of them shows a failed status, the other shows a success status.
What's really puzzling me is that, if I look at the status of BUILD CONFIG 2 for both projects, they both show a FAILED status.

So I guess my question is:

- what URL should I use to get a unique status icon, for all builds on active branches, in a particular project ?

Thanks.

Comment: I tried the URL you came up with and it seems to do the trick fine actually...